Problema con ejecutar un .exe en otras PCs
hice un programa en la escuela, es un menu ejecutable que manda a llamar a varios submenus y cada sub-menu puede abrir varios programas de python, todo esta en python, cree el .exe con la herramienta auto-py-to-exe, y me asegure de seleccionar todos los archivos necesarios para que el programa funcione, después me creo el .exe, el cual A MI me funciona bien, me ejecuta todos los programas de forma perfecta, pero cuando le paso el .exe a un amigo, no le funciona como a mi, tiene python instalado, le abre el menu y los submenus pero al escoger una opción que manda a llamar a los programas individuales salta este error: "No se encontró Python; ejecuta sin argumentos para instalar desde Microsoft Store o deshabilita este acceso directo en Configuración > Administrar alias de ejecución de la aplicación."
Notas:
A excepción de los menus Cada sub programa usa una o más librerías relacionadas con matemáticas.
El programa no tiene interfaz grafica, de hecho le indique a auto-py-to-exe que usara la consola de windows
He intentado mandarle el archivo con la extensión cambiada a .txt para que no le marque como virus y que luego le cambie el a .exe, y le sale el error mencionado, si se lo mando como .exe en un zip el error es el mismo
Aqui esta el codigo del menú, que yo creo es donde esta el problema:
import os
import subprocess

def clear_screen():
   os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

def mostrar_menu_principal():
   print("\n=== MENÚ PRINCIPAL ===")
   print("¿Qué método desea probar?")
   print("1 - Métodos de la Unidad 1")
   print("2 - Métodos de la Unidad 2")
   print("3 - Métodos de la Unidad 3")
   print("0 - Salir")

def mostrar_submenu_unidad1():
   print("\n=== MÉTODOS UNIDAD 1 ===")
   print("1 - Bisección")
   print("2 - Falsa Posición")
   print("3 - Secante")
   print("4 - Newton")
   print("0 - Volver al menú principal")

def mostrar_submenu_unidad2():
   print("\n=== MÉTODOS UNIDAD 2 ===")
   print("1 - Gauss Jordan")
   print("2 - Relajación")
   print("3 - Intercambio")
   print("4 - Jacobi")
   print("0 - Volver al menú principal")

def mostrar_submenu_unidad3():
   print("\n=== MÉTODOS UNIDAD 3 ===")
   print("1 - Cholesky")
   print("2 - Crount")
   print("3 - Doolittle")
   print("0 - Volver al menú principal")

def ejecutar_archivo(nombre_archivo):
   try:
       # Usar rutas relativas
       ruta_archivo = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), nombre_archivo)
       if os.path.exists(ruta_archivo):
           subprocess.run(['python', ruta_archivo])
       else:
           print(f"\nError: No se encontró el archivo {nombre_archivo}")
           input("Presione Enter para continuar...")
   except Exception as e:
       print(f"\nError al ejecutar el archivo: {str(e)}")
       input("Presione Enter para continuar...")

def menu_unidad1():
   while True:
       clear_screen()
       mostrar_submenu_unidad1()
       opcion = input("\nSeleccione una opción: ")

       if opcion == "1":
           ejecutar_archivo("biseccion.py")
       elif opcion == "2":
           ejecutar_archivo("falsa_p.py")
       elif opcion == "3":
           ejecutar_archivo("secante.py")
       elif opcion == "4":
           ejecutar_archivo("newton.py")
       elif opcion == "0":
           break
       else:
           print("\nOpción no válida")
           input("Presione Enter para continuar...")

def menu_unidad2():
   while True:
       clear_screen()
       mostrar_submenu_unidad2()
       opcion = input("\nSeleccione una opción: ")

       if opcion == "1":
           ejecutar_archivo("gauss_jordan_p.py")
       elif opcion == "2":
           ejecutar_archivo("relajacion.py")
       elif opcion == "3":
           ejecutar_archivo("intercambio.py")
       elif opcion == "4":
           ejecutar_archivo("jacobi.py")
       elif opcion == "0":
           break
       else:
           print("\nOpción no válida")
           input("Presione Enter para continuar...")

def menu_unidad3():
   while True:
       clear_screen()
       mostrar_submenu_unidad3()
       opcion = input("\nSeleccione una opción: ")

       if opcion == "1":
           ejecutar_archivo("cholesky.py")
       elif opcion == "2":
           ejecutar_archivo("crount.py")
       elif opcion == "3":
           ejecutar_archivo("doolittle.py")
       elif opcion == "0":
           break
       else:
           print("\nOpción no válida")
           input("Presione Enter para continuar...")

def main():
   while True:
       clear_screen()
       mostrar_menu_principal()
       opcion = input("\nSeleccione una opción: ")

       if opcion == "1":
           menu_unidad1()
       elif opcion == "2":
           menu_unidad2()
       elif opcion == "3":
           menu_unidad3()
       elif opcion == "0":
           print("\n¡Hasta luego!")
           break
       else:
           print("\nOpción no válida")
           input("Presione Enter para continuar...")

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Estas tratando de ejecutar python, eso obliga a que el usuario que lo quiera ejecutar tenga ese programa registrado y en una ruta conocida... no es la mejor idea...
